# Destructuring for get the first property of an object?

Tags: javascript

For arrays, we can define the properties depending on it's indexes like:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const [first, second, third] = arr;
console.log(first, second, third)
```

I'm just wondering if there's a possible solution to do it's reverse with objects like:

```js
const obj = {first: "a", second: "b", third: "c"}
    const {0, 1, 2} = obj; 
//expected: "a", "b", "c"
```

Comment: Objects don't have a "first", they aren't ordered. Also 0, 1 and 2 aren't valid identifiers. Neither of your snippets works, and it's not clear what you'd expect as an outcome.

Comment: Keys in object [don't have an order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes) You can use Map or Array only

Comment: @jonrsharpe try the first snippet. It will work. What I expect as an outcome is quite clear in the comment as I think. Secondly, the "like" word shows that it should work like in the example.

Comment: No it doesn't, I get a `SyntaxError` (e.g. `missing variable name` or `unexpected string`, depending on the implementation). And it might be clear to *you*, but if you're asking here it also needs to be clear to *other people*.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) or [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or even Object.values but the order in which you get the keys/values is [not guaranteed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_notes). You can also use named destructuring: `cost {hello} = {hello: 'world'}`

Comment: More info [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#destructuring)

Comment: `expected: "a", "b", "c"` - what does that *mean*, though? Is that an *array*? If not, the comma operator means the expression evaluates to simply `"c"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the values and assign this to an array for destructuring.

The order is actually dtermined by the insertation order or if a key is like a valid index of an array, it is sorted numerically to top.

```js
const
    object = { first: "a", second: "b", third: "c" },
    [first, second, third] = Object.values(object);

console.log(first, second, third);
```

For extracting a an arbitrary position, you vould take an object with an index an [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern) for a new valid variable.

```js
const
    object = { first: "a", second: "b", third: "c" },
    { 2: foo } = Object.values(object);

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't.

Objects are not designed to be ordered, so there isn't a first property per se.

You could convert an object into an array of its values first …

```js
const obj = {
  first: "a",
  second: "b",
  third: "c"
}
const array = Object.values(obj);
const [foo, bar, baz] = array;
console.log({
  foo,
  bar,
  baz
});
```

… but it is unlikely to be *useful* and it certainly wouldn't be intuitive code that is easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You do it like this for objects:

```
const obj = {foo: 123, bar: 'str'}

const {foo, bar} = obj
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const obj = {first: "a", second: "b", third: "c"}
const indexes = [0, 1, 2]
indexes.map( (val) => { return Object.values(obj)[val] } ) //["a", "b", "c"]
```